# declare a variable and select it in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, declare

In SQL Server, I can do the following to declare and select a dummy variable:

```
declare @dummy decimal;
set @dummy = 0;
select @dummy as dummy;
```

How can it be done in Oracle sql? the following doesn't work:

```
declare dummy decimal := 0;
select dummy as dummy;
```

EDIT:
The aim is to be able to replace an existing query string (which in itself is retrieved from a database), used from a client code (in C#, FWIW), with a dummy query.

Comment: What do you want to do with the final query? Some more context would, likely, get you more relevant answers.

Comment: @MT0, your'e right, I'll add some context.

Comment: Also, you are not using PL/SQL in your example. PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language. Using `SELECT` is just SQL (Oracle's dialect of SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DUAL` table:

```sql
SELECT 0 AS dummy FROM DUAL;
```

or, in the SQL/Plus client (and some others such as SQL Developer), create a bind variable:

```sql
VARIABLE dummy NUMBER;
BEGIN :dummy := 0; END;
/
SELECT :dummy AS dummy FROM DUAL;
```

or, from Oracle 12c, you can use PL/SQL and return a cursor:

```sql
DECLARE
  rc      SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_dummy NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    OPEN rc FOR SELECT v_dummy AS dummy FROM DUAL;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(rc);
END;
/
```

> The aim is to be able to replace an existing query string (which in itself is retrieved from a database), used from a client code (in C#, FWIW), with a dummy query.

Use a parametrized query and pass in a bind variable where you want to use the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DEFINE` as follows:

```
SQL> DEFINE DUMMY=5;
SQL> SELECT &DUMMY AS DUMMY FROM DUAL;

     DUMMY
----------
         5

SQL>
```

Comment: Is this an SQL/Plus (and a few other IDEs) specific solution or will it work with any client (i.e. Java, C, etc.)?

Comment: This will work in SQLPLUS and SQLDeveloper and other IDEs of the DB.

Comment: Including via ODBC/JDBC etc.?

Comment: Nope. ODBC/JDBC - No.. @MT0

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL?

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_dummy number := 0;
  3    retval  number;
  4  begin
  5    retval := l_dummy;
  6
  7    -- or:
  8    select l_dummy into retval from dual;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: my bad, @MT0 corrected me. it should simply be in Oracle sql, not pl\sql.